# How do I evaluate a single variable function with exponential with SymPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to use SymPy to calculate some expressions, but sometimes, using the `.subs()` function alone, or followed by `.evalf()`, does not give any float or integer values.

```
##--IMPORT
from mpmath import *
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x = symbols("x")

_fOfX = "e**x + x + 1"

if __name__== "__main__":
    #Function to sympy expression
    _sympyFunction = sympify(_fOfX)
    #Calcolo la derivata prima
    _dPrima = diff(_sympyFunction,x,1)
    _dPrima = _dPrima.subs(x,5)

    print(_dPrima.evalf())
```

And for those who want to know, yes I need to parse a string to get the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that sympy does not interpret `e` as `exp(1)`, but as the symbol `e`, just like it treats `x` as the symbol `x`. If you want sympy to understand what you want you could write `exp(1)` intstead of `e`.

See the example below on how sympy interprets string1 and string2

```
import sympy as sym

string1 = "e"
string2 = "exp(1)"

sym_string1 = sym.sympify(string1)
sym_string2 = sym.sympify(string2)

print(type(sym_string1))
print(type(sym_string2))

e = sym.symbols('e')
print(type(sym_string1.subs(e, sym.exp(1))))
```

So what you can do is either replace `e` in your string with `exp(1)` or replace it later. Your code could for example look like this:

```
from mpmath import *
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x = symbols("x")

_fOfX = "e**x + x + 1"

if __name__== "__main__":
    #Function to sympy expression
    _sympyFunction = sympify(_fOfX)
    #Calcolo la derivata prima
    _dPrima = diff(_sympyFunction,x,1)
    _dPrima = _dPrima.subs(x,5)
    #Replace e with exp(1)
    e = symbols('e')
    _dPrima = _dPrima.subs(e, exp(1))

    print(_dPrima.evalf())
```

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of e, be included in that 'from mpath import *' ?

Comment: It does get imported, but how should sympy know about it? Sympy can not take care of all the other packages you imported, as there are too many and even incompatible ones. So it only uses itself and it's own definitions. Always use `import *` with care. Imagine you would also have `from numpy import *`. Then you would end up with two independent (and from a technical point different) definitions of `e`.